# Displaying 2 different length columns from SQL query when pulling from 1 table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I use the following code to pull data from my table.

```
    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN VendorContactLName LIKE '%[s]'
        THEN VendorContactFName + ' ' + VendorContactLName + '''' END AS 'Test',
    CASE WHEN VendorContactLName NOT LIKE '%[s]'
        THEN VendorContactFName + ' ' + VendorContactLName + '''s' END AS 'Test2'
    FROM Vendors;
```

Currently, this returns 2 columns as it should, but where the first condition isn't true, it places "NULL" in the Test Column and where the second condition isn't true, it returns NULL in its respective column.  I'd like it to not do this, and instead incrementally add rows based on whether or not the condition is met and avoid the rows with NULL in them.

EDIT:  Not sure how it wasn't clear, but for a visual representation this is what DOES happen with the current code.

```
Test            Test2
NULL            Francesco Alberto's
NULL            Ania Irvin's
NULL            Lukas Liana's
NULL            Kenzie Quinn's
Michelle Marks' NULL
NULL            Anton Mauro's
NULL            Ted Maegen's
NULL            Erick Kaleigh's
NULL            Kaitlyn Anthoni's
NULL            Bill Leigh's
NULL            Kaitlin Hostlery's
```

What I want is this:

```
    Test            Test2
Michelle Marks'    Francesco Alberto's
                   Ania Irvin's
                   Lukas Liana's
                   Kenzie Quinn's
                   Anton Mauro's
                   Ted Maegen's
                   Erick Kaleigh's
                   Kaitlyn Anthoni's
                   Bill Leigh's
                   Kaitlin Hostlery's
```

Comment: Please show example data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case use a outer query to filter out `NULL` like below. Here `XXX` is the table alias for the inline query resultset.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
CASE WHEN VendorContactLName LIKE '%[s]'
    THEN VendorContactFName + ' ' + VendorContactLName + '''' END AS 'Test',
CASE WHEN VendorContactLName NOT LIKE '%[s]'
    THEN VendorContactFName + ' ' + VendorContactLName + '''s' END AS 'Test2'
    FROM Vendors ) XXX
WHERE Test IS NOT NULL AND Test2 IS NOT NULL;
```

(OR)

Using `ISNULL()` function like

```
SELECT ISNULL(Test, '') as Test, ISNULL(Test2,'') as Test2 FROM (
    SELECT 
CASE WHEN VendorContactLName LIKE '%[s]'
    THEN VendorContactFName + ' ' + VendorContactLName + '''' END AS 'Test',
CASE WHEN VendorContactLName NOT LIKE '%[s]'
    THEN VendorContactFName + ' ' + VendorContactLName + '''s' END AS 'Test2'
    FROM Vendors ) XXX
```

Comment: Not sure if I was supposed to edit something in your code when utilizing it, but I copied it exactly as is, and it just gives me 2 blank columns with the Test and Test2 headers.  Additionally, I'm assuming the XXX is for something, could you elaborate on the purpose of that being there? I tried removing it to test, and it doesn't seem to like it without something being there.

Comment: @TekGiant, see edit in answer if that helps. You can as well try with a `OR` condition like `WHERE Test IS NOT NULL OR Test2 IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: Ok, so, I tried your second example, which in face returns results.  But, it still doesn't achieve the desired goal I posted above, all it does it prevent it from placing the NULL text in the field as it populates the rows. So I end up with 2 columns of the same length, but the Test column ends up with mostly blank fields.  I don't want there to be blank spaces.  If this is not possible due to the nature in which Management Studio displays table data then that's okay, I'd just like to be sure that's what's limiting it.

Comment: @TekGiant, NO, you will not get the data exactly the way you posted. That's not how it works.

Comment: That sucks... Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to wrap it as sub select:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   Your statement here
)
WHERE Test IS NOT NULL AND Test2 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The reason NULL is being returned is because you aren't specifying an ELSE clause in your case statements.
   (see Return Types section:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

   ```
   SELECT 
   CASE WHEN VendorContactLName LIKE '%[s]'
       THEN VendorContactFName + ' ' + VendorContactLName + ''''
       ELSE 'Value' 
   END AS 'Test',
   CASE WHEN VendorContactLName NOT LIKE '%[s]'
       THEN VendorContactFName + ' ' + VendorContactLName + '''s'
       ELSE 'Value'
   END AS 'Test2'
   FROM Vendors;
   ```
2. Even if you avoid returning NULL on a false evaluation, the other issue you're likely going to run into is that you're building a table with two unrelated columns and setting them equal to eachother.
   Rather than produce a table with mismatched column lengths, Null values would be inserted to ensure columns were equal length:

   ```
   #   Test    Test2
   1   Foo     Thing1
   2   Thing2  Bar
   3   Smith   NULL
   4   Value   NULL
   ```

   In this case, IsNull() would set returned NULL values to a specified value, but may not offer any additional benefit.